# Create a visual studio initial solution, with a tool or extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-templates

I found myself repeat on the same structure over and over again in all new projects. Is there a tool that I can use to create my own initial template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your base project and export it as a project template (File -> Export Template).

This [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/creating-and-sharing-project-item-templates/) is a good source of information and walks through the process of packaging up your project template in a VSIX file for distribution.

There is an extension (the [Export Template Wizard](https://web.archive.org/web/20101223145651/http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24)) that you can get from the Online Gallery that provides a few more options than the standard Export Template, and is not as involved as creating the VSIX manually.  You can read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff527343%28v=vs.100%29), which also talks about template parameter substitution.

Comment: Do I can export a solution that will contain a few projects rather than a single project?

Comment: I don't think the Export Template Wizard does that, but using the VS 2010 SDK, you can create [multi-project templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx).  I haven't done that yet, so cannot comment on how difficult it is.

Comment: it's really simple, it's a vstemplate in the root folder template, like this: